# axios post request hangs on valid requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm using axios in my nodejs app to send requests to another service.
When I send a request and get 5xx or 4xx error codes in response - axios handles the request well and returns the error to the client.
When the request is well structured, it just hangs and the promise axios sends never resolves, leaving the client hanging indefinitely waiting for a response.
I've no idea what's causing only valid requests to hang, or how to further debug this.
Things I've tried so far -

- Send the requests (both failed and valid) using postman - they return error codes and OK codes as expected.
- Debug the node process in VScode, I can see that axios is internally looping indefinitely, waiting for the promise to resolve but I've yet to understand what's keeping the promise from resolving.
- axios version is a bit outdated so I've tried updating it but this created new issues so I decided to dial it back to the original version.

Some information on the versions of the app, in case relevant -

- node version - v9.11.1
- axios verion - 0.9.1

Snippet of axios request, redacted for security reasons -

```js
const Router = require('express').Router;
const router = Router();
const axios = require('axios').create({
    baseURL: 'https://some-service.com'
});

const auth-handler = require('auth-handler');

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    auth-handler.getToken('token-name')
        .then(token => {
            const body = {
                subject: "subject",
                body: "body"
            };

            const options = {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            };
            return axios.post('/'+req.body.route+'/endpoint?foo=bar', body, options);
        })
        .then(response => res.status(response.status).send(response.data))
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
            res.status(error.status).send(error.data);
        });
});
```

Comment: are you sure that you post to another service ? `axios.post('/'+req.body.route+'...` maybe you post on the same service, and looping with your express router ?

Comment: I'm positive. As you can see the other service is defined in baseURL when I define axios and like I wrote - if the request is malformed or invalid I'm getting the expected 4xx from the other service.

Comment: if you have control of the other service, have you tried logging requests' headers to spot the differences between axios call and postman call ?

Comment: I've been trying to avoid it since the other service is a legacy one and visibility into it isn't great, but I guess it's time to take off the kid gloves. Thanks.

Comment: Or you could setup a spy to monitor outgoing requests on your computer. Good luck !

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The answer to this is that axios has been resolving the promises as expected, there was just no indication for it on the client side of my program, only errors were indicated properly in the form.

I've added an indication for 2xx responses, and now all is well again.

Comment: What did you do exactly?

Comment: Could you please post your solution?

Answer (score 1):

Faced similar issue. Axios would get stuck in instance(request) step. Replacing *https* with *http* in URL fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Fo me it worked after using https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-request-throttle

```
static myFynction(urls): void {
    axiosThrottle.use(axios, {
        requestsPerSecond: 2
    });
    const getUrls = [];
    urls.forEach((url: string) => {
    const axiosCall = axios({
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                ...
            },
            url: url,
        })
        .then((response) => {
            return response.status;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            return error.message;
        });
    getUrls.push(axiosCall);
});
const responses = browser.call(async () => await Promise.all(getUrls));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. Like I said - this ended being an issue with the code handling axios responses in my case. Good to know you found a solution as well.